# heroku deploy error in RoR(Github deploy) what should I do with postgresql error?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, github, sqlite

I'm deploying small app from C9 to github then to Heroku!
In heroku deploy dashboard, it says it's been deployed, but when I open the app, it just gives me error msg. 
So I searched a lot of Stackoverflow answers and was following the direction from Heroku website(https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/sqlite3) to remove sqlite3 and install the gem pg.

I did replace gem 'sqlite3' to gem 'pg' and did 'bundle install', and then

It says I need to convert my   config/database.yml file, So I replaced it like this:

```
development:
  adapter: postgresql
  database: my_database_development
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
test:
  adapter: postgresql
  database: my_database_test
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

production:
  adapter: postgresql
  database: my_database_production
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
```

and then when I come back to c9 bash and type 'rake db:create',
it shows me

```
**rake aborted!
ActiveRecord::NoDatabaseError: FATAL:  database "my_database_development" does not exist**
```

this error.

someone said 'bundle exec rake db:setup' would work, so I did, and then it shows

```
**Couldn't create database for {"adapter"=>"postgresql", "database"=>"my_database_test", "pool"=>5, "timeout"=>5000}
/home/ubuntu/workspace/db/schema.rb doesn't exist yet. Run `rake db:migrate` to create it, then try again. If you do not intend to use a database, you should instead alter /home/ubuntu/workspace/config/application.rb to limit the frameworks that will be loaded.**
```

I don't know how to react to this msg.... when I type 'rake db:migrate' and it shows this again.

```
rake aborted!
ActiveRecord::NoDatabaseError: FATAL:  database "my_database_development" does not exist
```

I'm not using database, so maybe I can try something on 'config/application.rb' file, but how should I do??

Comment: `rake db:create` then `rake db:migrate`

Comment: I did 'rake db:create' already, not working as I've written...

Comment: do `rake db:reset`

Comment: same error like `rake db:setup` plus `PG::InvalidParameterValue: ERROR:  new encoding (UTF8) is incompatible with the encoding of the template database (SQL_ASCII)
HINT:  Use the same encoding as in the template database, or use template0 as template.
: CREATE DATABASE "my_database_development" ENCODING = 'utf8'`

Answer (score 0):

It wasn't necessary to change your `development` and `test` databases, those could still have used sqlite3 and so your C9 instance would have continued to work.

(Although there are some advantages to using a consistent adapter across all environments)

If this is just a hobby exercise I would be tempted to keep sqlite3 for development and test.

Also, Heroku replaces the database.yml with its own version so you don't need a production stanza in database.yml

You do need the `pg` gem, but you can specify it is only loaded in production and you can specify the `sqlite3` gem is only loaded in development and test.  Do that in your Gemfile and then bundle.

```
group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3'
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg'
end
```

If you want to use PostgreSQL in your C9 instance, you have to install PostgreSQL (the database, not just the adapter).  It's not a simple process.

This wiki explains how you would install it.

https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Detailed_installation_guides

Comment: I solved the problem with your answer and deploy new Heroku with new git not through Github. I didn't need database. Thanks!

Comment: That's great. If my answer helped please feel free to upvote it or accept it.

Answer (score -2):

one of the solution that you can create database manually this is easily solut